# How to make Azure AD authentication work outside localhost

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I created a blazor server app like this:

[image: Blazor server project creation wizard]

That works fine on my local machine. However, when deploying the website to azure I get the following error message: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

In the azure portal I navigated to the enterprise application that was automatically created during the project creation in visual studio. However, the "Homepage URL" is readonly.

[image: Homepage URL is readonly]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Instead of Enterprise application go to App registration click on Authentication under Manage group, in Authentication Menu you can specify redirect URL.

**Method 2:**

You can modify application manifest for redirect URL and save it after modification.

Considering AAD application is created using your own account you should be owner of this application and can be able to modify it.

Let me know for any question, happy to help!